# How to extract substrings from a string using regular expression

Tags: python

I have a string `s = "ATAATGCGTGGAATTATGACCGGAATC"` I would like to extract all substrings starting with `ATG` and ending with `GGA` . So the results would be `ATGCGTGGA` and `ATGACCGGA` .

This is what I have done so far but not working. Thanks for helping me in advance.

```
s = "ATAATGCGTGGAATTATGACCGGAATC"
x = re.findall('^ATG.+GGA$', s)
print(x)
```

Comment: Tha is perfectly working, your string is neither starting by ATG or endidng by GGA

Comment: JUst remove `^` and `$` from your regexp: `re.findall('ATG.+GGA', s)`

Comment: Note that "ATGCGTGGAATTATGACCGGA" is third solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `^` and `$` you are anchoring to start and end of line, don't do that if you want to find substrings. Also by default regex is "greedy", it will match the longest possible sequence.

You need to use `+?` for a non-greedy (aka lazy) match that matches the shortest sequences:

```
x = re.findall('ATG.+?GGA', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Symbols `^` and `$` refer to the beginning and end of the string, not the beginning and end of the substring.

Just remove `^` and `$` from your regexp: `re.findall('ATG.+GGA', s)`.

In addition, you might want to add `?` after the `+`, to stop at the first found `CGA` rather than the last: `re.findall('ATG.+?GGA', s)`

Refer to [Module `re`: regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in the official python documentation, for more information about `^`, `$` and `?`.

Comment: This results in one found substring `ATGCGTGGAATTATGACCGGA` because the `.+` match is greedy. See my answer :)